# Removing a nested list associated with a key and inserting into a new list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to remove nested lists that are associated with a key

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4} -> 1, {5, 6, 7, 8} -> 1, {9, 10, 11, 12} -> 2, {13, 14, 15, 16} -> 2};
```

In order to create two separate lists where;

`b` contains the nested lists associated with the key 1, but without the key;

`c` contains the nested lists associated with the key 2, but without the key.

Would anybody be able to help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
{b, c} = GroupBy[a, Last, Keys] /@ {1, 2}
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}},
>    {{9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}}

Alternatively, you can use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html) after reversing each element of `a`:

```
{b2, c2} = Values @ Merge[Identity] @ (Reverse /@ a) ;
{b2, c2} == {b, c}
```

> True

You can also get the same result using [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
{b3, c3} = Cases[a, Rule[p_, #] :> p] & /@ {1, 2} 
{b3, c3} == {b, c}
```

> True

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would this work this same for a list that had 0 for its key? Eg: a={{1,2,3,4}->0, {5,6,7,8}->1}

Comment: @Luke4737, if you mean something like `ax = {{1, 2, 3, 4} -> 1, {5, 6, 7, 8} -> 1, {9, 10, 11, 12} -> 
   2, {13, 14, 15, 16} -> 2, {stuff, etc} -> 0}` as input list, you can use
`{l0, l1, l2} = GroupBy[ax, Last, Keys] /@ {0, 1, 2}` (or more generally, `separatedlists = GroupBy[ax, Last, Keys] /@ ax[[All, -1]]`) Similarly, for other methods.

Answer (score 5):

With [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

```
Query[GroupBy[Values -> Keys] /* KeySort /* Values]@a
```

or without

```
Values@KeySort@GroupBy[Values -> Keys]@a
```

Both give

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}, 
>  {{9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}}
> ```

[`KeySort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeySort.html) ensures the key sets are order by their value.

Hope this helps.